# Globbing with negation in ZSH

Tags: shell-script, zsh, wildcards

I’m trying to get something like `ls **/*!(test).rb` to expand to all ruby files which do not end with “test”. However, everything I tried so far didn’t help. I tried turning on ZSH’s expanded globbing option, but no luck.

I know could just do something like `ls -l **/*.rb | grep -v test` but I’d really like to do it with globbing only

Answer (score 3):

```
setopt extended_glob; ls -d -- **/(^*test).rb
```

or

```
setopt ksh_glob; ls -d -- **/!(*test).rb
```

The different form from your version (`*!(test).rb`) will also match `foo-test.rb`, because the `*` matches the `foo-test` part of the filename, and the `!(test)` negation matches the empty string.

---

The "ksh-glob" form also works in `bash`, with `shopt -s globstar extglob`:

```
#! /bin/bash
shopt -s globstar extglob
ls -d -- **/!(*test).rb
```

Notice that in bash there should be a newline between `shopt -s extglob` and the use of an extended pattern, and the two may not be part of the same compound command or function.

Comment: The first one just matched everything like `**/*` would but the `ksh` version worked perfectly! Thank you so much :)

Comment: what version of zsh are you using? could try a simpler testcase like this: `zsh -c 'mkdir -p /tmp/a/b/c/d && cd /tmp/a && touch b/{{f,f-test}.rb,c/{f,f-test}.rb} && setopt extended_glob && ls **/(^*test).rb'`